# JS Query to toggle table rows is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle, nextuntil

I have the following html page

```js
$('.header').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0">
  <tr  class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Summary 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Summary 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Summary 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

when clicked on the `.header` row(s) they do not collapse or expand
I tried in latest versions of  firefox, IE and Chrome ... this did not work.

am i missing anything... 
New to JS/JQuery etc..

Comment: create js fiddle please

Comment: Have you included jQuery script in `$(document).ready(function(){ //Your code here });` ?

Comment: what is or how to create js Fiddle

Comment: @Pugazh Meaning should the jquery be like like this$(document).ready(function(){ $('.header').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(1000);
}); });

Comment: @siva Your example seems like working, can you guide me with the exact problem ?

Comment: The problem is when i open the html file in a browser, (IE firefox, chrome) this toggle does not work!

Answer (score 0):

For better use i create a class `.hidden` and i will toggle it on click.

look on

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jr47ychh/)

```
  $('tr.header').each(function(){
    var self = this;
    $(self).click(function(){
    $(self).nextUntil('tr.header').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```